# Accessing char member variable address of a structure

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a structure and i am trying to print the address of their member variables.
When tried to print the address of char member variable through &(f.c) i am not getting their address.

### Here is the code:

```
struct foo
{
        char c;
        short s;
        void *p;
        int i;
};

int main()
{
        cout << "Size of foo: " << sizeof(foo) << endl;

        foo f;
        cout << "Address of c: " << reinterpret_cast<void*>(&f.c) << endl;
        cout << "Address of c: " << &(f.c) << endl;
        cout << "Address of s: " << reinterpret_cast<void*>(&f.s) << endl;
        cout << "Address of s: " << &(f.s) << endl;
        cout << "Address of p: " << reinterpret_cast<void*>(&f.p) << endl;
        cout << "Address of p: " << &(f.p) << endl;
        cout << "Address of i: " << reinterpret_cast<void*>(&f.i) << endl;
        cout << "Address of i: " << &(f.i) << endl;


        return 1;
}
```

### Output

```
/pp/cplus/bas ]$ ./a.out 
Size of foo: 12
Address of c: 0xffbfe680
Address of c:                   //----------- &(f.c). Why this is empty.. 
Address of s: 0xffbfe682
Address of s: 0xffbfe682
Address of p: 0xffbfe684
Address of p: 0xffbfe684
Address of i: 0xffbfe688
Address of i: 0xffbfe688
```

just want to know why it is not printing when i tried accessing it through &(f.c)

Compiled using gcc version 3.4.6

Answer (score 9):

`cout` has an `operator<<` overload for `char*` which treats the argument like a pointer to a C-string and it tries to print all the characters in that C-string until it gets to a NUL (0) byte. To get around this behaviour, you have to cast the addresses to `void*` like you are doing every other line.

You have just experienced the reason that arrays are sometimes considered second-class data types because they are treated specially in some situations (i.e. arrays of `char` are treated differently by some things but not others).

The `Address of c:` is empty because that's what you get when you try to print a string pointed to by `&f.c`. As dark_charlie pointed out, using an uninitialised variable is undefined behaviour, so technically anything can happen, but the former is probably the explanation for what you're seeing (though we can only guess).

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that without the reinterpret cast &(f.c) is a char* pointer which is treated as a string by cout. Because you haven't filled the char with anything, you invoke an undefined behavior (i.e. it can print anything).